# convert images to gif error marking filters as finished

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif

I'm converting pretty large .png files to gif (2000X1000)

I used this article http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html about a year ago to write a script after interpolating to find a happy medium of simplicity of code. Today I noticed this tiny script is now erroring with

```
...
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'palette.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 16x16 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> paletteuse:default
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> paletteuse:palette
  paletteuse -> Stream #0:0 (gif)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 000001cb06eae700] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Output #0, gif, to 'out.gif':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, pal8, 1234x1088, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 2 fps, 100 tbn, 2 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 gif
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

Possibly due to the images getting bigger, I'm on Windows10, not that it's terribly relevant.

contents of movie.bat (note the %% needs removing if you run this code discretely)

```
del done.txt
REM creates a color palette file first
c:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -i %%02d.png -vf palettegen -y palette.png
REM use the palette file to speed up conversion
c:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -framerate 2 -loop 0 -i %%02d.png -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse -y out.gif
dir > done.txt
```

Now the 'Thread message queue blocking;' can be eliminated by adding -thread_queue_size 100, where 100 is larger than the number of input files, but the "filter" error message makes no sense to me since this script was working fine about a year ago. The "filter" here is bringing in the palette file, because without it, the script used to and still does generate horrid yellow artifacts (darker pixels become yellow) which is what happens if I only run:
`c:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 2 -loop 0 -i %02d.png -vf "format=rgba" -y out.gif`
I get the impression the pixel format is not the problem, since a few formats I guessed at had no impact on the result image, hence my use of a palette file in my little script.
No I don't want to use imagemagic, I want to be able to port this to macos, ubuntu and centos at some point, hence my tool choice here.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the issue. Show the **complete** log from your command. Provide the input files if they are required to duplicate this issue.

Comment: The images (30 of them) are 1 second apart screenshots banking detail/datas, will make a set of images up that repro this and then push them to someplace so other folk can try. Pretty sure it's the fact that they are larger than they used to be initially when this did work. Need sleep now.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Only when the number of frames is large and only when using palettegen / paletteuse. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think I am ready to do a weekend coding stint to produce a repro of the issue now @XylemFlow . (I am wanting to be converting browser screenshots to video to build a "test-recorder" and since most tests now pass, it dropped down as a priority a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding this happens for mixed png type inputs. That is if your PNG files are stored with an implicit palette (png8 format) and others without (png32 format). Please ensure that the internally used encodings are identical and not using a palette already

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue (`Error marking filters as finished`) when using the palette (`paletteuse`). I solved it forcing all my PNG images to have the same size.